# How to personalize installing path when installing cython?

Tags: installation, cython

I am installing cython 0.18. However, I dont know how to set installing path when installing it. I prefer to install it under my personal home directory because I don't have permission to install files under /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.

Thanks,

Li

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient :

Add the following lines to your `~/.profile` :

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/YOUR/DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.18
export PATH=$PATH:~/YOUR/DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.18/bin
```

Then you should be able to :

```
CC="gcc"   \
CXX="g++"   \
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```